# c# for statement variable usage outside of the statement

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, console.writeline

```
for (i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
     //display data here
}

Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I want to display the amount of times total i iterated outside the for statement so it only displays ONCE.

Comment: You haven't declared the variable `i` in the for iterator, so your code could be compiled only if you declare the variable before the for. In that case the WriteLine after the for loop works as  expected. So what's the problem?

Comment: Not sure the downvotes are warranted here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `i` declaration before your for loop:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
     //display data here
}

Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
int i = 0;
for(;i < 50; i++)
{
    // Do some stuff
}
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `i` outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

define variable i before the loop and initialize it to 0;